# É aceito perguntas que pedem exemplos de conteúdo?

Tags: debate, perguntas, razões-fechamento

É aceito como pergunta válida no SOpt pedir um exemplo de determinado conteúdo? Ex: [Simple example of threading in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266168/simple-example-of-threading-in-c). Esta pergunta pede um simples exemplo de multithreads em C++. Por vezes encontrei este tipo de pergunta no SOen abertas em com uma alta taxa de visualizações e aqui no SOpt vi várias na fila de fechamento.

Comment: É uma boa pergunta a sua...

Comment: Eu acho válido, muitos conteúdos não tem uma boa documentação ou exigem um grau de experiencia meio elevado sendo que uma explicação bem "mascadinha" poderia ajudar bastante.

Comment: Concordo contigo, Ricardo. Também acho válido nesses casos, quando a documentação é ruim. Mas mesmo quando existe documentação, um exemplo em português pode ser útil. Afinal, a ideia do SOPT é justamente ajudar também quem tem dificuldades com o idioma inglês.

Comment: Mas como sinalizar para que os membros não sinalizem como amplo demais ou outro motivo? porque eu já varias perguntas na fila de analise para serem fechadas por ela pedirem exemplo de algum conceito/tecnologia.

Comment: Ótima pergunta! Quem é developer sabe como é complicado e muitas vezes impossível entender uma documentação sem exemplos ou explicação de uso prático.