# Referente a tutoriais

Tags: debate

Exite alguma coisa na area 51, ou é possível fazer aqui mesmo no SOPT pedidos de ajuda para instalação/configuração de softwares?

Hoje por exemplo eu visitei 9 paginas na internet para ver como instalar um controlador de dominio com o samba4, óbvio que cada pagina que visitei explica de um jeito, então eu tenho que ver se a pagina aceita comentários e aguardar/torcer para um único autor ver um dia e talvez me responder, e acho que aqui no SOPT o retorno é bem mais rápido e com mais dinâmica de interação.

Minha dúvida é esta: Posso postar aqui no SOPT este tipo de pergunta? se não tem alguma comunidade "Stack Exchange" que isso seja permitido ?

**obs:** Vejo que os falantes do idioma português tem essa necessidade de ampliar, de evoluir do sistema antigo de foruns para este sistema do SO, então perguntas do tipo [ajuda demonstre um exemplo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3838/%C3%89-aceito-perguntas-que-pedem-exemplos-de-conte%C3%BAdo) esta sendo cada vez mais necessário.

Comment: Podes sempre fazer a pergunta e ver o que acontece.

Comment: Dúvidas de ajuda de instalação e configuração de ferramentas relacionadas ao desenvolvimento se software fazem parte do nosso escopo (até que se prove o contrário), mas acho que a forma de como você vai pedir isso pode influenciar na decisão de fechar a pergunta ou não. Geralmente o que eu vejo é que se você falar: "Alguém tem um tutorial sobre X?" sua pergunta poderá atrair muitas respostas de baixa qualidade muitas vezes apenas com links e levará a entender que sua pergunta ou é ampla demais ou baseada em opinião. [...]

Comment: [...] E portanto fechada não por causa do assunto em questão, mas por causa da maneira como foi perguntada

Comment: @Math e nesse caso onde a ferramenta não é relacionada ao desenvolvimento de software, esta mais para mecanismo de governança de TI, geralmente quando a pergunta não envolve código-fonte diretamente a comunidade já põe na fila de fechamento

Comment: SneepSNinjA, acho que sim. Sugiro seguir a sugestão do @JorgeB.

Comment: Particularmente, acho que seria off-topic. Tendo em vista que a ferramenta não é usada no desenvolvimento de software.

Comment: @emanuelsn li aqui no SOPT que a comunidade aceita tudo o que for específico da area de TI, não somente código-fonte, um exemplo é configuração do apache, isso é um serviço assim como um DC, ou estou enganado ?

Comment: Aceitar **tudo** da área de TI não. http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264/ Mas, conforme o @JorgeB. já te sugeriu acima, faça a pergunta. Vamos ver qual será o comportamento da comunidade.

Comment: o tudo ficou mesmo meio pesado, mas um tutorial desse nível é tão técnico ou mais do que este outro exemplo http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1436/12032

Comment: @SneepSNinjA Caso ache válido, pode criar uma nova resposta na pergunta que linkei no comentário anterior e ver a opinião da comunidade.